# Is there any way to delete S3 object which is created with object lock 'Compliance' Retention mode?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can we delete S3 object which is created with object lock 'Compliance' Retention mode?

Answer (score 7):

Not until the retention period is over, according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-overview.html#object-lock-retention-modes):

> In Compliance mode, a protected object version can't be overwritten or
>   deleted by any user, including the root user in your AWS account. Once
>   an object is locked in Compliance mode, its retention mode can't be
>   changed and its retention period can't be shortened. Compliance mode
>   ensures that an object version can't be overwritten or deleted for the
>   duration of the retention period.

Comment: Adding to this: the only way to delete an S3 locked object on compliance mode before its retention period is over is by **deleting the AWS account**.

Answer (score 0):

We can only delete the object version after retention expired and there is no legal hold.